# Replace onclick in html with event handler in Js

Tags: onclick, event-handling

Im working on a project for school which i have to finish quite soon. But i used the old "onclick" in HTML method and that is not allowed. So now im trying to move it to Js with an Id tag. this is my current code.

HTML:

```
<label for="male">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="userName" oninput="changeUserName()">
```

Javascript:

```
function changeUserName() {
employee.userName = setEmployee('userName');
showEmployee();   }
```

How do i change the code so that i use event listerers? i tried to search youtube and the forums but didn't figure it out..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try something like this ? `document.getElementById("yourelement").onclick = function() { alert("clicked"); };`

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element by id and then set the oninput like this:

```
document.getElementById("userName").oninput = function() {
  // do something
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hr6dLkuf/5/

Comment: document.getElementById("userName").oninput = function changeUserName() {
    employee.userName = setEmployee('userName');
    showEmployee();
}   This is what i have now but i get an error "
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'oninput' of null"   And in the Fiddle i see there's still a "oninput" in html to let it function

Comment: so it looks like your `document.getElementById("userName")` selector isn't returning the dom element. check the id is correct.